# How to check a user input matches the particular regular expression in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

```
handleModalField = event => {
    var value = event.target.value;
    var isDisabled = true;
    if (
      value &&
      //value.length >= 5 &&
      /^[A-Za-z]{5}$/i.test(value)     
    ) {
      isDisabled = false;
    }
    this.setState({
      modalField: value,
      isDisabled: isDisabled
    });
  };
```

The above is my code segment to be fixed...I want to modify my regular expression to check whether the 'value' variable contains A-Z and a-z and the length should be at least 5 characters.

Comment: You can make your method appear in a [more compact way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60206632/11299053) and avoid excessive regexp.

Comment: The answer you have accepted will fail for more than 5 letters, which is not what you requested by *'...be at least 5 characters'*. Consider other answers as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make Regex object and check whether input match to your regular expression

ex:

```
    let reg = RegExp(/^[A-Za-z]{5}$/i);
    reg.test("hello")
```

so in your example it something like this

```
//define this to constant
const reg = RegExp(/^[A-Za-z]{5}$/i);

handleModalField = event => {
    var value = event.target.value;
    var isDisabled = true;
    if (reg.test(value)) {
      isDisabled = false;
    }
    this.setState({
      modalField: value,
      isDisabled: isDisabled
    });
  };
```

for More regex expression [visit here](https://regexr.com/)

for Dynamic value assing to Regex input like this

```
let n = 6;
let regs = RegExp(`^[a-z]{${n}}$`,"i");
```

Comment: above will match for ***exactly*** 5 letters, if you happen to have 5+ letters it will fail, besides, with `/i` flag, there's no need to use `A-Z`

Comment: for that, you can use dynamic value pass to regex object see above updated code

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
/^[A-Za-z]{5,}$
```

If you put the /i tag you make it case-insensitive so you don't check for lower and uppercase anymore

And {5} only validates if string has length 5. For 5 or more you need to use {5,}